# pilight send raw code [433MHz]

Tags: gpio, wireless, home-automation, wiringpi

I have set up a 433Mhz receiver and sender at my raspberry pi using pilight in order to remote control a power socket (Flamingo FA500S). Unfortunately, this one is *self-learning* and therefore not supported by the pre-programmed protocols in pilight. That's why I read the raw code of my rc (delivered with the power socket):

> --[RESULTS]--
>
> time:           Mon Jan  9 14:35:14 2017 hardware:       433gpio
>
> pulse:          3
>
> rawlen:         50
>
> pulselen:       302
>
> Raw code: 302 906 302 906 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906 302 906
>   1208 302 302 906 302 906 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906 302 906 1208
>   302 302 906 302 906 302 906 906 302 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906
>   302 10268

Now, I want to send these codes using my 433Mhz sender.

I tried this, which did not work (the power socket did not react):

```
pilight-send -p raw -c "302 906 302 906 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302
906 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906 302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906
302 906 1208 302 302 906 302 906 302 906 906 302 302 906 1208 302 302
906 302 906 302 10268"
```

Has anybody an idea, what I am doing wrong? Maybe because I did not set the `rawlen` / `pulselen` (which I do not know how to set using the `send` command).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this python library but if your 433MHz transmitter is connected via a single pin (not including power) like the plain jane ones I do not think you will be able to control it directly with a Raspberry Pi; those radios require sub-millisecond level precision to produce an irregular pulse and the Pi cannot do that reliably, at least not in a context where python is involved (because of the OS).  Also beware if you have not used them (the radios) before they can have a much shorter range than most people would hope for unless the transmitter is provided more than 5V power.

Comment: @joan GPIO 18 (I configured the Pin correctly; I get an output when sending)

Comment: @goldilocks I understand your point. But this library can send and receive the signal; it worked at least for most people I've read on the internet.

Comment: @joan `/etc/pilight/config.json`

Comment: I rebooted and I get output on GPIO17.  The code isn't reliably sent but I read it a couple of times as the 24 bit code 1118484.  I suggest you use my [_433D](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D) software with `./_433D -t18 1118484`.  The timing will likely be far more accurate.

Comment: What's the distance between your transmitter and the outlet? Mine wasn't working on an outlet across the room behind a couch. I lifted it up from behind the couch on an extension cord and it worked. Then I added an antenna to the transmitter and now it works on outlets anywhere in the house.

Comment: Do you have a remote that the outlet came with? You could confirm your raw code using the receiver...